# Xsane Menu exceeds screen size. Unable to move or resize it

Tags: gnome, menu, scanner, xsane

When utilizing the manual controls when using Xsane, the menu for these controls exceeds my screen size. Normally, I just use <kbd>ALT</kbd> plus the left mouse button to move the menu up above the top menu bar.

However, the top of the menu has become locked from moving above the Desktop menu bar. I am unable to move the top of this menu above the desktop upper menu bar to access the buttons at the bottom of this menu. So now I can't return the menu to normal size.

[image]

I tried closing the program and restarting it. This was no help. The menu started up still exceeding the screen size and still locked from being moved above the desktop upper menu bar.

All of the controls for this menu are at the bottom of it. And this is the portion that I can not get access to. This menu can not be resized.

Uninstalling it and reinstalling Xsane was no help either. I was hoping for a reset here. But when starting it back up, the menu was still extended beyond the screen, and was still locked.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME.

This is a program that I use a lot. But I have no idea why the program has been locked to not pass above the top menu bar.

I can do a screenshot of the menu bar which looks like this. But I am unable to access the controls at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I had someone elsewhere jump to the conclusion that this problem was on a Netbook. It is not. It's on a desktop computer with a 32" monitor which has a resolution of 1366 x 768.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you needs a 1920 screen with Xsane. I just got a 1920x1080 monitor in tonight. I had been using my old 1366x768 monitor for many years. It actually has the same resolution as a a Windows Laptop that I sometimes use.

But I finally broke down and purchased a new 1920x1080 monitor. It makes a world of difference. All of the Xsane menus fit on the screen at the same time. Other programs seem to go through an adjustment as they load.

So Xsane is working perfect now, as long as I am using a 1920x1080 monitor.

Comment: I used a TV with HDMI cable.  Appalling bad conception of window manager.

Answer (score 1):

this can be easy solved:

- Goto xsane setup
- goto tab Display
- remove hook "main window size fixede"
- Restart xsane, no You have scrollbars!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had made a previous backup of all of my "HOME" files, which included the Xsane configuration files. It finally occurred to me that I could copy the older configuration files to the current .Xsane directory. This solved my temporary problem of getting Xsane to work again.

However, the larger problem of using the manual adjustments still exists within the Xsane program.

Comment: I think removing `~/.sane` will solve the problem though possibly also wipe out other settings.